# Matlab 2014b javax error with plots in ubuntu

Tags: java, matlab, ubuntu, plot

I recently installed Matlab 2014b on a Packard Bell LJ65 laptop with Ubuntu 14.04, and every time I open it the following error pops up on the command:

```
javax.media.opengl.GLException: X11GLXDrawableFactory - Could not initialize shared resources for :0
        at jogamp.opengl.x11.glx.X11GLXDrawableFactory$SharedResourceImplementation.createSharedResource(X11GLXDrawableFactory.java:316)
        at jogamp.opengl.SharedResourceRunner.run(SharedResourceRunner.java:295)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: javax.media.opengl.GLException: Startup Class Loader-SharedResourceRunner: Error making temp context(1) current: display 0x7f53a421e050, context 0x7f53a4247610, drawable X11OnscreenGLXDrawable[Realized true,
        Factory   jogamp.opengl.x11.glx.X11GLXDrawableFactory@4c932b8e,
        Handle    0x6800002,
        Surface   WrappedSurface[ displayHandle 0x7f53a421e050
    , surfaceHandle 0x6800002
    , size 64x64
    , UOB[ OWNS_SURFACE | WINDOW_INVISIBLE ]
    , X11GLXGraphicsConfiguration[X11GraphicsScreen[X11GraphicsDevice[type .x11, connection :0, unitID 0, handle 0x7f53a421e050, owner true, ResourceToolkitLock[obj 0x52109ee8, isOwner true, <4130bb6f, 666195d8>[count 2, qsz 0, owner <Startup Class Loader-SharedResourceRunner>]]], idx 0], visualID 0x221, fbConfigID 0xbb,
        requested GLCaps[rgba 8/8/8/0, opaque, accum-rgba 0/0/0/0, dp/st/ms 16/0/0, dbl, mono  , hw, GLProfile[GL2/GL2.sw], on-scr[.]],
        chosen    GLCaps[glx vid 0x221, fbc 0xbb: rgba 8/8/8/0, opaque, accum-rgba 0/0/0/0, dp/st/ms 24/0/0, dbl, mono  , hw, GLProfile[GL2/GL2.sw], on-scr[.]]]
    , surfaceLock <10b4cc6b, 4dd88d5e>[count 1, qsz 0, owner <Startup Class Loader-SharedResourceRunner>]
    , X11DummyUpstreamSurfaceHook[ 64x64]
    , upstreamSurface false ]]
        at jogamp.opengl.x11.glx.X11GLXContext.createImpl(X11GLXContext.java:346)
        at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.makeCurrentWithinLock(GLContextImpl.java:662)
        at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.makeCurrent(GLContextImpl.java:561)
        at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.makeCurrent(GLContextImpl.java:518)
        at jogamp.opengl.x11.glx.X11GLXDrawableFactory$SharedResourceImplementation.createSharedResource(X11GLXDrawableFactory.java:292)
        ... 2 more
```

I thought I could ignore it, since the program runs as normal for most of the tasks. But, when trying to plot, the following error appears:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.media.opengl.GLException: Profile GL_DEFAULT is not available on X11GraphicsDevice[type .x11, connection :0, unitID 0, handle 0x0, owner false, ResourceToolkitLock[obj 0x6860dc76, isOwner false, <2f29fc83, 6d8114a5>[count 0, qsz 0, owner <NULL>]]], but: []
    at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.get(GLProfile.java:901)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.getDefault(GLProfile.java:632)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLCapabilities.<init>(GLCapabilities.java:84)
    at com.mathworks.hg.peer.JavaSceneServerPeer.getCaps(JavaSceneServerPeer.java:147)
    at com.mathworks.hg.peer.JavaSceneServerPeer.doCreateCanvas(JavaSceneServerPeer.java:676)
    at com.mathworks.hg.peer.JavaSceneServerPeer.access$200(JavaSceneServerPeer.java:50)
    at com.mathworks.hg.peer.JavaSceneServerPeer$2.run(JavaSceneServerPeer.java:650)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

and no plot is produced.

I searched and found many problems with javax but not this one exactly. Any suggestions?

EDIT:
There is also an error appearing when loading matlab from the terminal

```
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Comment: How are you starting the program? Which graphics cards/drivers are you using?

Comment: I always run it from the terminal by calling:
`~/MATLAB/R2014b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB`

And regarding graphics I have: Gallium 0.4 on NVA8

Comment: I just realized there is another error message appearing in the terminal when I start the program. I included it in the original question.

Comment: It looks like the issue is jogl, ( java opengl ). It appears to be trying to load the incorrect 3d drivers. Does glxgears work for you? You might have to contact math works. I tried installing 2015a to see if I get similar issues, but Licensing is taking forever.

Comment: glxgears works but it gives me around 60fps

Comment: From the matlab website it says to use vendor provided graphics drivers. I am not sure how easy it is for you to switch drivers. When I load r2015a I also get a couple libGL errors, but no exceptions.

Comment: Problem solved. But thanks for the help matt!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it on my own following what was suggested in http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/170276-matlab2014b-generates-libgl-error-unable-to-load-driver-nouveau_dri-so-at-startup

basically, first download this set of drivers:

`wget ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/elrepo.org/extras/el6/x86_64/RPMS/mesa-dri-drivers-8.0.5-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64.rpm`

Then unpack it with:

`rpm2cpio mesa-dri-drivers-8.0.5-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64.rpm | cpio -idmv`

(if rpm2cpio is not installed then `sudo get-apt rpm2cpio`)

and copy the file in `WhereEverYouUnpacked/usr/lib64/dri/nouveau_dri.so` to `/usr/lib/dri/`

Note that the copying into `/usr/` has to be done as root

Answer (score 0):

just use Terminal to open matlab,**input `./MATLAB_PATH/bin/matlab`into a terminal**,you will find everything is fine.